# QGIS Error clipping raster?

Tags: raster, clip, qgis-2.14

I use QGIS 2.14.10

I am trying to clip a raster with a vector layer mask (shapefile)using the clipper tool (gdal). There is an offset betwween the resulting raster and the vector mask (see picture below).

I also tried with the saga script : clip raster with polygon. This one is working correctly but can only open a temporary file. If i try to save hard file i have this message : "ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable."

I need to clip a raster with a polygon ina script.

[image]

Comment: Your datasets probably have different coordinate systems

Comment: I don't think it come from that. I have the same coordinate system

Comment: And the project and output too?

Comment: yes. I Use the same coordinate system for project and all layers. And when i try to use the SAGA script "clip raster with polygon" i don't have this problem

Comment: If you look at the top of the picture. You'll see that the result is not only shift but also that it is not exactly the same shape

Comment: ok, I see. Try to run another tool from gdal: "clip raster by mask layer". And make sure you check the "Keep resolution of output raster" option

Comment: I try with the gdal tool : "clip raster by mask layer" checking the "Keep resolution of output raster" option but i get the same result

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's coming from the rasterize command : the polygon vertices are on the center of each raster source pixel. When the polygon is rasterized, the pixel are shift of 1/2 pixel.